# Polygon drawing cursor hangs while try to draw polygon on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Change your message to the following:

I have created a mapping application using gmaps drawing library. The system is complete and it seems to work great but I have a small problem. When the user draws with the polygon tool the cursor hangs. You will see a red line being created and than it will just stop drawing.

I have identified that if you click on the polygon draw tool and just move the + cursor from the top of the page to bottom you will see the + cursor periodically change. Its in these areas that create the drawing problem.

Can someone take a look at it and let me know why while in drawing mode cursor changes to pointer.

[Click HERE](http://www.joomlarealestatewebsites.com/mapsearch)

Do city search using input form stating "Enter Location or Address". Type in ross it will do auto-complete search and gives you the drop down option of "Rossmoor" click on the name and search will run. Than try to draw the polygon on map by clicking on "Polygon Search" option above the map inside yellow area. You might have to draw a few times for it to start having problems.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: no issues there for me, in which browser this problem occurs?

Comment: What browser are you using? It seems to work for me on XP professional x64 with chrome 24.0.1312.57